# Processing2.1.1 nullPointerException when trying loadTable()

Tags: nullpointerexception, processing

I'm getting a nullPointExeption when trying to loadTable.
here is my code.

```
String twitterFile = "output2.csv"; 
String twitterDataFile = twitterFile;

ArrayList<Twitter> tweets = new ArrayList();

void setup() {
  size(1000, 600, P2D);
  smooth();
  Table twitterCSV = loadTable(twitterDataFile, "header, csv");
}
```

Any ideia on what could it be?

thanks a lot

Comment: Is "output2.csv" in data folder in sketch folder?

Comment: yes! it is. It was s header problem. It was missplaced inside my csv. Thank you